# Improving Matlab graphing performance

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, graphing

I am using Matlab 2014b interfaced through a serial connection with an arduino and am trying to increase the performance of the graphing as it is too slow for displaying the sampling rate that I need. 
I am graphing the input from 3 separate sensors and need to display them on their own graphs in a GUI. I only graph the most recent 500 points to try and reduce speed issues related to plotting large numbers of points. I have used the tic toc functions to find where the bottle neck is and it occurs specifically at the plot code. The following is what i have so far. I need the sampling to occur Ideally at 100 samples per second but worse case 50 could work.

```
state=get(hObject, 'Value');
if state==1
global stop_state;
stop_state = 0;
pause(1);
stop_state = 1;
cla;
while_length = 1000;
count = 1;
i = 1;
flushinput(handles.s7);
while count <= while_length
    t = tic;
    t1 = tic;

    data = fscanf(handles.s7);
    [S1 S2 S3] = strread(data, '%d %d %d','delimiter',', ');
    S1_data(i) = S1;
    S2_data(i) = S2;
    S3_data(i) = S3;

    if i<=100
        d_S1 = (1:i);
    else 
        d_S1 = (i-100:i);
    end

    drawnow();
    axes(handles.axes1);
    xlabel('time');
    ylabel('Presure (mmHg)');
    plot(d_S1,S1_data(d_S1),'b*');
    axes(handles.axes2);
    xlabel('time');
    ylabel('Presure (mmHg)');
    plot(d_S1,S2_data(d_S1),'b*');
    axes(handles.axes3);
    xlabel('time');
    ylabel('Presure (mmHg)');
    plot(d_S1,S3_data(d_S1),'b*');

    i = i + 1;
    count = count + 1;
    time = toc(t1);
    disp(time);
    disp(t2);

if stop_state == 0 
    break;
end 
end
time1 = toc(t2);
end
```

Comment: It's faster to modify the lineseries' [`'XData'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_XData) and [`'YData'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_YData) directly rather than looping the `plot` calls.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that and see how much it changes the speed.

Comment: You might read through [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/animation-techniques.html) and the related examples linked there. You should move everything that doesn't change (e.g., `xlabel`) outside of your `while` loop. Calls to `disp` or any printing out will also make the loop run more slowly too. Also, consider buffering several calls to `strread` before plotting. Finally, it's not clear why you're calling `drawnow` before rather than after updating the plots.